# Does the fact that MacOS runs on a BSD core mean that it is a better choice for that hardware?

Tags: drivers, macintosh, bsd, distributions

Of the different distributions of Unix/Linux available for my Mac hardware, does BSD have an advantage because it's what is run under the GUI for MacOS, or does the Mach kernel abstraction keep any optimisation of hardware getting to the BSD layer?

If BSD is not the favored distribution, it's there a distribution which claims better Mac hardware support?

Answer (score 2):

Better is very opnion based, but...

No there is no inherent better-ness to one OS or another on Apple hardware it it's self.

That said, Apple hardware is closed and proprietary.  So the best running OS for that hardware is the "Only" OS that apple supports. To be clear, they don't support it because it's the best. It's the best because it's the "only" OS that is supported on the devices.

That is of course excluding Boot Camp.

So to sum it up. There is no hardware reason why "any" OS or distro would work any better on Apple hardware. You could take any OS apply drivers for the hardware and get a working OS.

That said Apple is a "walled garden" so, not going to be easy to do without apple support.

Comment: I'll give an example of how one distro might be better;if distro X had more commits for Apple specific hardware drivers. That's just an example. There is already a link between BSD and Apple hardware, but I don't know if that goes beyond the Mach kernel or not. In other words does the BSD code base have better Apple hardware support because MacOS uses BSD?  You don't address this.

Comment: I do, or I meant to. BSD does not have base line better support for apple hardware then anything else. OS X uses a base line of a BSD kernel  (and other tools) then modifies them. With out those modifications vanilla BSD would run just as well or just as poorly as Linux (or others) with out hardware specific patches.

Comment: Apple has pushed many things to open source. But their kernal and their "tools"/GUI is not one of them. So Plan old mainline BSD would run about as well as anything else on Apple hardware.